# How to send waysiprint pdf by mail

Tags: django, weasyprint

I'm trying to generate a pdf file from an HTML template using Weasyprint python package and I need to send it via email using.

Here's what i have tried:

views.py :

```
       user_info = {
            "name": 'nadjib',
        }
        html_string = render_to_string('Proformas/command.html')

        html = HTML(string=html_string,base_url=request.build_absolute_uri())
        # html.write_pdf(target='/tmp/mypdf.pdf');

        fs = FileSystemStorage('/tmp')
        with fs.open('mypdf.pdf') as pdf:
          response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
          response['Content-Disposition'] =  'filename="Commande.pdf"'
          pdf = weasyprint.HTML(string=html_string, base_url=request.build_absolute_uri()).write_pdf(
              stylesheets=[weasyprint.CSS(string='body { font-family: serif}')])
          to_emails = ['nadjzdz@gmail.com']
          subject = "SH INFOR FACTURE"
          email = EmailMessage(subject, body=pdf, from_email='attaazd@gmail.com', to=to_emails)
          email.attach("Commande".format(user_info['name']) + '.pdf', pdf, "application/pdf")
          email.content_subtype = "pdf"  # Main content is now text/html
          email.encoding = 'us-ascii'
          email.send()
        return response
```

the pdf is rendered successfully but not sent by mail ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from weasyprint import HTML
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.core.mail import send_mail, EmailMultiAlternatives


mail = EmailMultiAlternatives(
    'title',
    'text',
    from_email,
    [to_email,],
)
mail.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    
render_from_template = render_to_string('template.html', context={'context': 'context'})
pdf_file = HTML(string=file)

mail.attach(f'ticket.pdf', pdf_file.write_pdf(), 'application/pdf')

mail.send()
```

EDIT :
You can also use get_template()

```py
from django.template.loader import render_to_string, get_template

def create_pdf(context):


    template_name = 'template.html'
    template = get_template(template_name)
    html = template.render(context)
    pdf_binary = HTML(string=html).write_pdf()

    return pdf_binary

context = {'foo':'bar'}
mail.attach(f'ticket.pdf', create_pdf(context), 'application/pdf')
```